# Mac Blender 2.82 Simulation Issues

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, osx

OK so I know I'm on the S list using a Mac for 3D these days, but it is what it is.

I'm running 2.82 and the improvements in the UI are impressive. I'm a C4D user, but want to check out Blender's Fluid and Smoke. I started with 2.8 and couldn't get ANY simulation to bake so I could see anything. Sometimes it will look like it's calculating, but nothing at the end. Sometimes it will zoom through and "calculate" in less than a second.

I then downloaded the latest build, 2.83 alpha. I set up a simple fluid sim and boom. I could see the simulation. Great. I freed the bake and added some obstacles to test everything. Nothing. I haven't been able to get any results except that one time. I've read many posts, watch tons of tutorials, changed lots of settings all to no avail. I'm not talking about rendering issues where Eevee and Cycles and GPUs come in to play, I'm just try to see ANYTHING.

Here's a link to a super simple file I set up. Maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for taking a look.

[Simple Fluid Setup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8bnk2b31x88mqc/FluidTest.blend?dl=0)

Comment: OK so Smoke and Fire+Smoke seem to work now. No idea why. Now this is interesting. When I select my Domain and change it to Liquid, on screen it changes back to a solid cube. Could this be a clue as to why Liquid sims don't work at all?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your file. I changed the render engine to Cycles and in physics properties - chase from modular to replay (this allows you rendering during your animation - so you haven't to waitlists till the end of the render).

I deleted your flow object and created it new.
Type: Flow
Flow Type: Liquid
Flow Behavior: Inflow
nothing else

activated liquid

It works :)